# how to create complex nested object while iterating list of string arrays

Tags: java

I have an input like this

```
private String[] one = {"North America","USA","IL","ch","chicago"};
private String[] two = {"North  America","USA","WI","ma","madision"};
private String[] three = {"Asia","India","AP","nlr","nlr"};
private String[] four = {"asia","india","TN","ch","chennai"};
```

and will add to List like this.

```
private List<String[]> entities = new ArrayList<>();

    private void initializeStringArray(){
    entities.add(one);
    entities.add(two);
    entities.add(three);
    entities.add(four);
 }
```

I want now this entities to be converted to nested objects like
Continent->Country->State->District->City. Would like to what will be the best possible solution to create nested objects. It is very confusing while creating nested objects. Can anyone give me best solution.

```
public class Continents{
   private String name;
   private Collection<Country> countryCollection;
}

public class Country{
 private String name;
 private Collection<State> stateCollection;
}

public class State{
private String name;
private Collection<District> districtCollection;
}

public class District{
 private String name;
private Collection<City> cityCollection;
}

public class City{
private String name;
}
```

Comment: Smells like homework... Maybe make a generic class?

Comment: I guess you need a “World” class that has a list of continents? And generally I would recommend switching lists with maps, so that you can achieve faster access to the objects (for example: world will have map from continent name to a continent instance)

Comment: We are here to help you fix your solution. Not to create a solution for a question. Try something and when you get stuck or get errors, we can help out.

Comment: But as tungstenx suggested these classes seem to be very similar so that you may create only one class (that has a “name” field and a “sons” field) and reuse it.

Comment: This is not an actual business object model of my project. just to make you understand I created similar example but it has nested object with different number of attributes  in each class.

Answer (score 0):

CAVEAT: I do not know how to determine which solution might be the 'best possible solution'.  Here, though, is ***one*** possible solution, maybe not the best....

I assume that you wish to have only one instance of 'North America' which is used for both 'chicago' and 'madision' .  So maybe create a class 'World' that has a dictionary of continents:

Untested code:

```
public final class World {
    public static final World shared = new World(); // singleton
    private Map<String, Continent> continents = new HashMap<>();

    private World() {}  // enforce singleton

    public final Continent getContinent(String name) {
        String lowerCaseName = name.toLowerCase();
        Continent continent = this.continents.get(lowerCaseName);
        if (null == continent) {
            continent = new Continent(name);
            this.continents.put(lowerCaseName, continent);
        }
        return continent;
    }

}
```

World acts as a collection of unique Continent instances, and as a factory for new Continents.

Continent would then have a map of Country, and act as a factory for country, with pattern repeating down your hierarchy.

Then your code becomes similar to (untested code):

```
Continent continent = World.getContinent(one[0]);
Country country = continent.getCountry(one[1]);
State state = country.getState(one[2]);
.........
```

The key point here is that each level acts as a container and a factory for unique instances of the next level down.

Comment: I need to fill the object in the way I have given above. After filling the objects I have to generate an xml file. That is my project requirement.